# Uglify SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am trying to use gulp in order to minify a folder containing JS files. However, one of the files has the above error, preventing it from being minified.

I managed to catch and print the error, which I've partially printed here:

```
JS_Parse_Error {
 message: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())',
 filename: 'ex.js',
 line: 189,
 col: 25,
 pos: 6482,
 stack: Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> ... ) 
 plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
 fileName: '.../js/ex.js',
 showStack: false
}
```

The file in question contains the following, shortened:

```
function() {
  ...
  $.confirm({
    buttons: {
        confirm: function() {
            $.post('/ajax-handler', {
                    ...
                })
                .done( function(response) {
                    var data = filterResponse(response);
                    if (data['status'] == 'success') {
                        sleep(1000).then(() => {
                    *       ...
                        });
                        sleep(5000).then(() => {
                            ...  
                        });

                    } else {
                        console.log('Oops!');
                    }
                })
                .fail( function(err, status, response) {
                    ...
            });
        },
        cancel: function() {}
    }
 });
  ...
}
```

I added the "*" above in order to indicate the exact position listed by JS_Parse_Error.

Comment: Looks like you're not converting the code to ES5 before minifying, so uglify doesn't understand what `() => {}` means. If you change it to `sleep(1000).then(function() { ... })` it should work unless there are other errors

Comment: Alright, had to sort out a couple other errors, but that definitely helped and everything's working now. For the record, since I've been seeing it thrown around a lot, would you know what the difference is between ES5 and ES6?

Comment: you can check http://es6-features.org/. There are lots of differences

Comment: @Alexander I have an npm package that exhibits this error, how come it is not converted to ES5 since the rest of the project is being converted?

Comment: @Qwerty I'll admit, it's hard for me to tell without knowing more about what you're trying to minify, unfortunately. In my case above I had to manually change the code to ES5.

Comment: I believe I am minifyinf everything. I write my project in ES6, I use some npm packages and some are in ES6 as well - those exhibit these UglifyJS errors. I was wondering why my code is transpiled and minified without problems, but those packages are not. Maybe another transpiler got my code into ES5 disregarding modules, then there was a mess of ES5+ES6 code and UglifyJS got mad. Anwyay, I have solved it. I taught UglifyJS ES6.

Answer (score 66):

## // Update

[From the comments ~ **@imolit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375468/uglify-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc/43674989?noredirect=1#comment94347861_43674989)

> #### v2.0.0 (2018-09-14) - BREAKING CHANGES [*(link)*](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2018-09-14)
>
> Switch back to [uglify-js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) (uglify-es is abandoned, if you need uglify ES6 code please use [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin)).

---

## Original answer before the update...

I hope you can get inspired by this solution which works with webpack. *(link below)*

## Simply teach UglifyJS ES6

There are two versions of UglifyJS - **ES5** and **ES6** (Harmony), [see on git](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony)
ES5 version comes by default with all the plugins, but if you install a Harmony version explicitly, those plugins will use it instead.

package.json

```
"uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony"
```

or

```
npm install --save uglify-js@github:mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony

yarn add git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony --dev
```

---

#### Webpack

To use it with webpack install also the webpack plugin

```
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev

yarn add uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --dev
```

then import the manually installed plugin

```
var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
```

and replace it in code

```
-  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ ... })
+  new UglifyJSPlugin({ ... })
```

---

For more webpack info (Installation/Usage) see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#install

Comment: Hi, how to use it in webpack? I have this in my prod pipeline `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` and after installing the harmony version I still get the "punct()" errors. ta

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek You replace `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` with `new UglifyJSPlugin()`. Don't forget to import `var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');` The webpack's included plugin is the old one, this is how you explicitly tell to use the one you installed.

Comment: Yes, that helped! Thank you.

Comment: Just a heads up, this solution does not work as is, as later versions of uglifyjs-webpack-plugin aren't compatible with the uglifyjs2#harmony branch. For uglify-webpack-plugin, I had to use v0.4.4. For uglify-js, I used git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony-v2.8.22. Hope that helps somebody

Comment: FYI, this is fixed in the beta of uglifyjs-webpack-plugin. Use `"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.2"` in your package.json to get it working again with the fix above.

Comment: Wouldn't `--save-dev` be more fitting in this case?

Comment: Thanks, solved it by uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.0.0-beta.1, by the way, i found uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.0.0-beta.2 may throw some errors, so just downgrade to 1.0.0-beta.1.

Comment: N.B: The Webpack section is outdated. `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` [no longer supports ES6](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2018-09-14) and they recommend the [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) instead.

Comment: @imolit Thanks for the heads up. I updated the answer a little, but due to my lack of context, I would like to ask you to edit in some details. I put a placeholder for you there ;)

Comment: Not sure what you'd like me to update. I temporarily solved the problem with parsing ES6 by running `yarn add uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.3.0 --dev`, which does include support for ES6. I think the *correct* approach would be to install the terser-plugin, but since I haven't tried it, I cannot recommend it. Also, all this assumes that people are running webpack, while the question was related to gulp which may not necessarily involve webpack.

Answer (score 17):

`npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev` is not enough

The main problem is `"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6"` in [webpack's package.json](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json)

According to [semver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver), `^0.4.6 := >=0.4.6 <0.5.0`. Because of the leading zero, `webpack` will never use the `1.0.0-beta.2`.

So after running `npm i -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@beta`, you need to do one more step which is `rm -rf node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`. Then webpack will pick up the version from `node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` instead of `node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`

Update on 2018-04-18: webpack v4 does not have this issue

Comment: Or rimraf node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglify-js in my case. Great addition WooD

Comment: I am using webpack v4.12.0 and this was necessary

Comment: Using "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.20.0" I had to do this as well.

Answer (score 8):

Add the `babel-preset-es2015` dependency to fix this.

And also add `'es2015'` in `.babelrc` file.

```
json
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: As of 2018, this is what worked for me: **`"presets": ["env"] `**

Answer (score 6):

If you got this error using Grunt (grunt-contrib-uglify) the solution is to install ES6 version of the plugin:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify-es --save-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same issue,  i found a great answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422437/execjsprogramerror-unexpected-token-punc-expected-punc-when-running/38605526#38605526)  that helped me to reach the the file that was causing the error.

Go to Rails Console and Paste:

```
JS_PATH = "app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js";
Dir[JS_PATH].each do |file_name|
  puts "\n#{file_name}"
  puts Uglifier.compile(File.read(file_name))
end
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Super helpful indeed. Thanks, Hamza!

Answer (score 3):

For me it had nothing to do with Uglify not working correctly, but rather a dependency (in this case empty-promise) that has not been compiled to ES5 yet. As we just imported the raw source file, but babel is only transpiling files outside of node_modules, uglify got confused by the ES6 syntax.

Simply check if any dependency you've recently added might not have a "dist" build.

Comment: How to check if a dependency has a dist-build?

Comment: @PeterRader packages usually have a `dist` folder (or something similar) under their directory in `node_modules`. Just look if the index file in their `package.json` points to a compiled source directory. If not, you need to add them to your babel config.

Answer (score 0):

Add stage-3 to presets in .babelrc file.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

hello,
The problem is that other methods do not start with window.
This is how I solved it.
I got this error after putting if statement.
To solve the problem, I called the fbAsyncInit method with "window" prefix.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
```

it fixed it.