# Cannot build vue project

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to build my vue project and push it into github pages.

I'm trying to run `npm run build` but all I'm getting is this :

```
> my-domain@1.0.0 build /Users/macbookair/Workspace/fun/mine/web
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules

Hash: 2399923ef57865258a1f                                                           
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 9252ms
       Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    build.js  740 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
build.js.map  919 kB       0  [emitted]         main

ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (() [build.js:503,6]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! andre.js.org@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the andre.js.org@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookair/.npm/_logs/2018-02-27T09_19_23_677Z-debug.log
```

I also tried to run `npm run build; push-dir --dir=dist --branch=gh-pages --cleanup` and all I'm getting is this :

```
> andre.js.org@1.0.0 build /Users/macbookair/Workspace/fun/mine/web
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules

Hash: 2399923ef57865258a1f                                                           
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 9524ms
       Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    build.js  740 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
build.js.map  919 kB       0  [emitted]         main

ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (() [build.js:503,6]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! andre.js.org@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the andre.js.org@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookair/.npm/_logs/2018-02-27T09_22_29_715Z-debug.log
```

I don't really know how to build it since I'm new to Vue, I'm using the `webpack-simple` vue template

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375468/uglify-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option: 
https://github.com/creotip/vue-particles/issues/7

But maybe the better options will be reinstall npm

Answer (score 0):

You use Version: webpack 3.11.0

Try to install latest version

```
 $ npm i -D webpack@latest
 $ npm run build
```