# when generating build of AngularJS project getting Uglifying source .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js failed

Tags: angularjs

Creating build of angularjs project inside folder dist /script I am not getting one `script.js` file.

I have tried grunt build --prod --force command for creating the build

```
Running "uglify:generated" (uglify) task
JS_Parse_Error {enter code here
  message: 'Unexpected token: punc ())',
  filename: '../../.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js',
  line: 5122,
  col: 59,
  pos: 161138,
  stack:
   'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (D:\\...node_modules\\uglify-node_modules\\uglify-js\\lib\\parse.js:1427:20)' }
>> Uglifying source .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js failed.
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: punc ()). 
Line 5122 in .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.jsenter code here
 Used --force, continuing.
```

Warning: Cannot read property `min` of undefined Used --enter code hereforce, continuing.

Comment: Hard to know without the source and exact line
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375468/uglify-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc

Comment: Finally It's working fine, generating build successfully Firstly I have changed work-space I was using then used command "npm i natives" then grunt build --prod --force